# Panel with Collapsible Set and Listview set to em25 too wide in 'Overlay' Mode

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I have some nested recursive functions which dynamically create collapsible with listviews that are in a side panel.  I found the default 17em to be too small, especially as the nested text starts to get short.  So I found the styles in the css which set it and I overrode those to use 25em.  This might be a bit too much after testing on some devices. However I digress.

The thing I am here to ask is why my collapsible overflows the panel when I use data-display="overlay", when I set it to 'reveal' it looks fine.  I thought it might be all my nested content, so I made a fiddle with static content here:  http://jsfiddle.net/LF6UR/

```
            <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-display="overlay" data-position="left" data-position-fixed="true" data-swipe-close="true" data-dismissible="true">
```

and I can see it is not that, perhaps there is some other CSS property for the panel that I am not aware of.  There seem to be lots of niggly little settings to get to know with this framework.  Hope someone out there can help because I really think 'overlay' is better than pushing my main content area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQM adds a negative left and right margin to collapsibles within the collapsible set.  You can override the margin like this:

```
.ui-collapsible-set .ui-collapsible{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LF6UR/1/)**

Also, changing your collapsible set to data-inset="true" fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes it works, but it will inset every collapsible then, and I have collapsibles nested inside.  If I inset every one of them, which is more intuitive for navigation I run out of space of the text the deeper it goes.

Comment: Here is a fiddle of what I mean..                                        http://jsfiddle.net/magister/LF6UR/3/

Comment: Here I try to add a custom css class just to the 1st level, but of course the jqm css overwrites it which mean all nested collapsibles are also inset  http://jsfiddle.net/magister/LF6UR/5/

Comment: Look under Header 2 to see the nested collapsible

Comment: can I do this without 'inset'ing all collasibles

Comment: use !important to override CSS. See if this works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LF6UR/6/ , you can tweak the margins to your tase...

Answer (score 0):

a solution without setting collapsibles to inset...which is important because I have nested collapsibles is to simply set the 'magic' .ui-panel-inner class which JQM puts in as an 'enhancement' but which makes it a bit difficult for traditional webdevelopers to know to apply styles to their controls.

```
.ui-panel-inner {
    /*width: 25em;*/
    padding: .2em 1.2em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/magister/LF6UR/8/